# Twitter Timeline Not Showing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Twitter Timeline not showing on this code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gavi Soul Offical Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/THE_HOMIE_GAVI... async src=" //platform.twitter.com/widgets.js " charset="utf-8 ">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <!doctype html> <!doctype html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Gavi Soul Offical Website</title> <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css.css" /> </head> <body> <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/THE_HOMIE_GAVI... async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> </body> </html>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your code is **riddled** with HTML syntactical errors, which is why it is not displaying as you'd expect. Please correct these, ensuring that you follow the correct [**HTML structure**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html). W3Schools has a good [**introduction tutorial**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) on this. Once complete, you can **validate** your code with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you're closing your `<a>` tag and attempting to run your `<script>`. You seem to be missing a section of code there.

In addition to this, your code is **riddled** with HTML syntactical errors, which is why it is not displaying as you'd expect. You'll need to correct these, ensuring that you follow the correct [**HTML structure**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html).

I've gone ahead and done this for you in the following example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gavi Soul Offical Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/THE_HOMIE_GAVI">Link</a>
  <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js " charset="utf-8 "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note the following:

- Only one doctype
- A closing `"` in the `href` attribute for the `<a>` tag
- A closing `>` and `</a>` for the `<a>` tag, with content in-between
- An opening `<script>` tag

W3Schools has a good [**introduction tutorial**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) on this. Once complete, you can **validate** your code with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/).

Simply replace the `href` in your `<a>` tag  (currently `https://twitter.com/THE_HOMIE_GAVI`) with the relevant Twitter link.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ran this exact code except fixed the username, the timeline still doesn't show.

Comment: The timeline shows correctly for me when replacing the username in the above code with a valid one. This can be verified [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4c2dkm8c/). Keep in mind that StackOverflow has a **sandboxed** code source, so won't allow Twitter's scripts to function correctly. The above code **will** work correctly when replacing the username and deploying to a non-sandboxed environment.